# C++ set allowing duplicates?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to solve the interview problem from leet code to remove duplicates from a vector of ints.

Below is my my code for the answer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int>::iterator itr;
        set<int> temp;

        for (itr = nums.begin(); itr != nums.end(); itr++) {
            if (temp.insert(*itr).second == false) {
                nums.erase(itr);
            }
        }
        return nums.size();
    }
};
```

I've added includes for completion.

The problem I've run into is if I have an input vector as so [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5] my function will only erase the duplicates that are not 1 or 2.

Thus my answer will be [0,1,1,2,2,3,4,5].  My understanding is that set will not allow duplicate values but I don't understand why 1 and 2 is still duplicated.

Comment: The code doesn't output anything, how do you know that the set contains duplicates?

Comment: @mkreiger1 leetcode runs the code in the background and returns the result which in this case is an array with no duplicates.  Since the function accepts a pass by reference the caller is aware of the changes to the array.

Comment: You might consider [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) operating directly on the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because this is undefined behavior.

```
  nums.erase(itr);
```

`std::vector`'s `erase`() method ***invalidates*** all existing iterators "at or after the point of the erase". Since `itr` is the "point of the erase", `itr` is no longer a valid iterator when `erase()` returns. Subsequent attempt to increment it, in the `for` loop's iteration results in undefined behavior.

Your C++ textbook will have a more complete explanation of how to use the value that `erase()` returns, and what it means, in order to correctly avoid undefined behavior; but the capsule summary is:

```
  itr=nums.erase(itr);
```

Note that now `itr` points to the value in the vector that's ***already after*** what was `erase`()d, which might be `end()`; whether it's `end()` or not you obviously don't want to increment it immediately. It should be obvious that you want to check if the immediately following value in the vector is ***another*** duplicate too, don't you agree?

So what you'll need to slightly rework your `loop` so that it:

1. Uses `erase()` correctly
2. Only increments the iterator if it ***does not*** `erase()` the duplicate value.

Comment: Thanks!  I see now, I misunderstood the functionality of erase!  I appreciate you pointing this out!